# extracting out elements from a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a 1x600 (rowsxcolumns) vector, say "A", where i want to access the following columns of A:

```
166   (column value is 2)
256   (column value is 5)
346   (column value is 8)
436   (column value is 10)
526   (column value is 13)
```

After extracting out these columns, I want to add their respective values:

```
sum = 2 + 5 +8 + 10 + 13
```

Can any one help me out on how to first extract the columns , and then sum up their values? Thanks!

Comment: See: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html and http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
sum(A([166, 256, 346, 436, 526]))
```

e.g.

```
A = [5,4,3,2,1];

A([3, 5]) %// i.e. get the 3rd and 5th column
```

returns 
`3  1`

so `sum(A([3, 5]))` returns `4`

Comment: Yeah! But, first of all how to access the columns

Comment: @user2762192 yes sorry, I mixed up your values with your indexes. This is correct though.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
idxToSum = [166 256 346 436 526]; % or another way to give find your indices
yourSum = sum(A(idxToSum));
```